# Why is True returned when checking if an empty string is in another?

Tags: python, string, python-internals

My limited brain cannot understand why this happens:

```
>>> print '' in 'lolsome'
True
```

---

In PHP, a equivalent comparison returns false (and a warning):

```
var_dump(strpos('lolsome', ''));
```

Comment: So perhaps PHP is wrong here? The empty string *is* present, in all strings.

Comment: I actually think this is an interesting question.  I hope it doesn't get closed while I'm researching.

Comment: not a question to be down-voted so hard.

Comment: @Marcelo I am sorry, your last edit changes the meaning of the question drastically. So, I had to revert your edit.

Comment: @thefourtheye I edited because I do want to find a empty string into a string with chars, and strpos signature is `strpos ($haystack ,$needle)`, so, my first PHP example was wrong, just as you have stated in your answer.

Comment: Indeed, this is not as much about why is Python behaving right, but why is PHP behaving wrong (as always).

Comment: I can't understand why anyone expects otherwise.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> For the Unicode and string types, `x in y` is true if and only if *x* is a substring of *y*. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Note, *x* and *y* need not be the same type; consequently, `u'ab' in 'abc'` will return `True`. *Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.*

From looking at your `print` call, you're using 2.x.

To go deeper, look at the bytecode:

```
>>> def answer():
...   '' in 'lolsome'

>>> dis.dis(answer)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('lolsome')
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

`COMPARE_OP` is where we are doing our boolean operation and looking at the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l2548) for `in` reveals where the comparison happens:

```c
    TARGET(COMPARE_OP)
    {
        w = POP();
        v = TOP();
        if (PyInt_CheckExact(w) && PyInt_CheckExact(v)) {
            /* INLINE: cmp(int, int) */
            register long a, b;
            register int res;
            a = PyInt_AS_LONG(v);
            b = PyInt_AS_LONG(w);
            switch (oparg) {
            case PyCmp_LT: res = a <  b; break;
            case PyCmp_LE: res = a <= b; break;
            case PyCmp_EQ: res = a == b; break;
            case PyCmp_NE: res = a != b; break;
            case PyCmp_GT: res = a >  b; break;
            case PyCmp_GE: res = a >= b; break;
            case PyCmp_IS: res = v == w; break;
            case PyCmp_IS_NOT: res = v != w; break;
            default: goto slow_compare;
            }
            x = res ? Py_True : Py_False;
            Py_INCREF(x);
        }
        else {
          slow_compare:
            x = cmp_outcome(oparg, v, w);
        }
        Py_DECREF(v);
        Py_DECREF(w);
        SET_TOP(x);
        if (x == NULL) break;
        PREDICT(POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE);
        PREDICT(POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE);
        DISPATCH();
    }
```

and where [cmp_outcome is in the same file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l4466), it's easy to find our next clue:

```c
res = PySequence_Contains(w, v);
```

which is in [abstract.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/abstract.c#l2381):

```c
{
    Py_ssize_t result;
    if (PyType_HasFeature(seq->ob_type, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_SEQUENCE_IN)) {
        PySequenceMethods *sqm = seq->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
        if (sqm != NULL && sqm->sq_contains != NULL)
            return (*sqm->sq_contains)(seq, ob);
    }
    result = _PySequence_IterSearch(seq, ob, PY_ITERSEARCH_CONTAINS);
    return Py_SAFE_DOWNCAST(result, Py_ssize_t, int);
}
```

and to come up for air from the source, we find this next function in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PySequenceMethods.sq_contains):

> ```
> objobjproc PySequenceMethods.sq_contains
> ```
>
> This function may be used by `PySequence_Contains()` and has the same signature. This slot may be left to *NULL*, in this case `PySequence_Contains()` simply traverses the sequence until it finds a match.

and [further down in the same documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Contains):

> ```
> int PySequence_Contains(PyObject *o, PyObject *value)
> ```
>
> Determine if *o* contains *value*. If an item in *o* is equal to *value*, return `1`, otherwise return `0`. On error, return `-1`. This is equivalent to the Python expression `value in o`.

Where `''` isn't `null`, the sequence `'lolsome'` can be thought to contain it.

Answer (score 21):

I dug deeper and found [the source code corresponding to the `strpos` function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ffc49acabc3e331022c4e9423cf85f6bb900da20/ext/standard/string.c#L1813),

```
    if (!Z_STRLEN_P(needle)) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Empty needle");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
```

They consider the empty string being searched as a problematic case. So, they are issuing a warning and returning `false`. Apart from this I couldn't find any document discussing why it is being considered as a problem.

As far as Python is concerned, this behaviour is well defined in the [Comparisons section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in),

> Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.

Comment: Haha, this is awesome, with you going into the PHP source and me into the Python source, this question is really well solved.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, from math:

> The empty set is a subset of every set

The same logic works here. You can consider `''` an empty set. And therefore, it's a subset of every *string* set, since they must be the same type.

```
>>> a = ""
>>> b = "Python"
>>> a in b
True
>>> set(a).issubset(b)
True
>>> a = set() #empty set
>>> b = set([1,2,3])
>>> a.issubset(b)
True
>>>
```

But be careful! A subset and a membership are [different things](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/656336).

[image]

Comment: The empty string is empty set logic doesn't work with other Python sequences. `set([]).issubset(set([1,2,3]))` is `True`. But, `[] in [1,2,3]` is `False`. Same goes to `tuple`. The empty string is empty set logic is wrong.

Comment: Screenshot of text is rarely useful here on [so]. The text cannot be searched for, nor copy-pasted. Always include the text itself, at least in the alternate text of the image. The UI elements in this specific screenshot are noisy and confusing (can be mistaken for actual controls when skimming the page).

Comment: @NizamMohamed `in` operator for a `list` only work for individual items, not a sequence of items, e.g. `[1, 2] in [1, 2, 3]` will also evaluate to `False` as the item `[1, 2]` is not present as an item for the list on the RHS.  `1 in [1, 2, 3]` will evaluate to `True` as that is how the `in` operator will function for a list on the RHS.  The logic for the `in` operator on the `str` on the RHS will match against the whole sequence provided on the LHS, not individual characters in the `str`, hence any empty sequence will be present in any sequence, as per logic.

Answer (score 5):

> The empty string is the unique string of length zero.
>   The empty string is the identity element of the concatenation operation.
>   The empty string precedes any other string under lexicographical order, because it is the shortest of all strings.
>   The empty string is a legitimate string, upon which most string operations should work.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string)

```
 > strlen("");
=> 0
 > "a" . "" == "a";
=> true
 > "" . "a" == "a";
=> true   
 > "" < "\0";
=> true
```

From above, it seems PHP treats the empty string as a valid string.

```
> strstr("lolsome", "");
strstr(): Empty needle :1
```

But it doesn't seem to consider the empty string as fully legitimate one. Most probably PHP is the only language which doesn't allow the substring to be searched within a string to be an empty string.

**Is it a defensive mechanism? Obviously, programmers don't have to protect the needle with `if`. If so, why other languages allow this test to pass!!! Language designers have to answer**

What's a Python string made up of?

```
>>> ''.count('')
1
```

Obviously The empty string has one empty string.

```
>>> 'a'.count('')
2
```

One element string has two empty srings.

```
>>> 'ab'.count('')
3
```

So it seems Python string is concatenation of one element strings. Each element in a string is sandwiched between two empty strings.

```
>>> "lolsome".split('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: empty separator
```

But here Python contradicts the validity of the empty string. **Is it a bug?**
[Ruby](https://repl.it/CYpv/0) and [JavaScript](https://repl.it/CYpw/0) pass the test here.

```
 > "lolsome".split("")
=> ["l", "o", "l", "s", "o", "m", "e"]
```

I've compiled several language examples from [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Substring), it's *interesting* to note that they all *allow the empty string* in substring search and return true.

[AWK](http://ideone.com/eGNIET)

```
awk 'BEGIN { print index("lolsome", "") != 0 }'
```

[C](https://repl.it/CYcF/1)

```
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", strstr("lolsome", "") != NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

[C++](https://repl.it/CYbQ/0)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "lolsome";
    std::cout << (s.find("") != -1) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[C#](https://repl.it/CYbN/0)

```
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string s = "lolsome";
    Console.WriteLine(s.IndexOf("", 0, s.Length) != -1);
  }
}
```

[Clojure](http://ideone.com/gsuWym)

```
(println (.indexOf "lolsome" ""))
```

[Go](https://repl.it/CYan/1)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)
func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Index("lolsome", "") != -1)
}
```

Groovy

```
println 'lolsome'.indexOf('')
```

returns 0, on error returns -1

[Java](https://repl.it/CYav/2)

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("lolsome".indexOf("") != -1);
  }
}
```

[JavaScript](https://repl.it/CYbT/0)

```
"lolsome".indexOf("") != -1
```

[Lua](https://repl.it/CYbi/0)

```
s = "lolsome"
print(s:find "" ~= nil)
```

[Perl](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTG1FVmdSX2hPRkE)

```
print index("lolsome", "") != -1;
```

[Python](https://repl.it/CYcg/0)

```
"lolsome".find("") != -1
```

[Ruby](https://repl.it/CYbr/0)

```
"lolsome".index("") != nil
```

Comment: C `strstr` also finds the empty `needle` at the beginning of a `haystack`. Considering that so many PHP string functions are modelled after their C counterparts (though there is no *strpos*), this is somewhat surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 2 piles of similar objects, say, best stanzas of your favorite poet, of 5 and 2 respectively. Does bigger set contains smaller set? How to check:
1) for any stanza in the smaller pile you may find it in a bigger one.
2) smaller pile doesn't contain something which is absent in bigger one.

So we may use this pseudocode to check:

```
for object in smaller:
    if object not in bigger:
       return 'we found object from smaller absent in bigger'
    else:
       go to next object
return 'all is ok - all objects from smaller are in bigger'
```

If you haven't found such an object, you come to the end of algo, and think smaller is a subset of bigger.

Now imagine smaller pile is of 0 stanzas.
Applying the same rules above, we perform 0 checks and also do not find object from smaller which is absent in bigger.

So it's correct and handy to deem empty string as a subset of any other string. Even itself. And this is realized in python.

```
    >>> '' in 'adfsf'
    True
    >>> '' in ''
    True
```