# How come empty value is matching with array value in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

I am matching an empty value with an array element which has one value in it and the array does not have any empty values. However, still this script works.

```
import re

b = ""
links_check_arr = ['Arunsdsdds']
for links_find in links_check_arr:
    if b in links_find:
        print  links_find
        print b
```

How come it is working when `b` is empty and the array element is `'Arunsdsdds'` (which has no empty value in it)?

Comment: An empty string is contained in every non-empty string (and obviously in any other empty string). Use `==` instead of `in`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Python returns True when checking if an empty string is in another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-python-returns-true-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another)

Answer (score 2):

An empty string is always considered to be part of any string:

```
>>> "" in "abcd"
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The empty string is a substring of *every* string in Python. This is because the substring of length 0 of any string `s[0:0]` is equal to the empty string.

A proper way to check if a string `s` is not empty is simply `if not s:`, as empty strings are "falsey".

To check if something is *equal* to the empty string, just use `==` as opposed to `in`.

Answer (score 0):

tristan gives a detailed answer in the post [Why Python returns True when checking if an empty string is in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-python-returns-true-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another). The important sentence is there:

> Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other
>   string, so "" in "abc" will return True.

You find this sentence in the Python 2.7. reference, article [Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) in the chapter *Comparisons*. Or for Python 3 in [Expressions, chapter *Membership test operations*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations).