# endswith() function of a string gives contradictory results

Tags: python

I was just fooling around in the Python console when I noticed these four results of four simple one line statements:

`1. "x".endswith("")
True`

`2. "x".endswith("x")
True`

Then I tried to strip the white-spaces from the statement, when they gave me these results:

`3. "x".strip().endswith("")
True`

`4. "x".strip().endswith("x")
True`

How can all of the results be `True`? How can a string function return `True` for ending with both `"x"` and `""`? Isn't this contradictory or am I missing something here?

Python 2.7 on PyCharm on Windows 10.

Comment: This question seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-is-true-returned-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another

Comment: "How can a string function return `True` for ending with both `"x"` and `""`?" Look at it this way. `"Hello"` ends in `"Hello"`,`"ello"`, `"llo"`, `"lo"`, `"o"` and `""`. There is nothing contradictory there.

Comment: I got the answer. +1 for @Amadan's cpmment. Precise explaination

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a string ends with a space try `"x "`

For example, `"x ".endswith(" ")` returns `True`, but `"x ".strip().endswith(" ")` returns `False`.

`""` is an empty character, what you are trying to do wont work. The space character is presented like this: `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.strip()` function removes all whitespace at the start and end of the string it's called on. Your string, `"x"`, has no whitespace around it, so it will not change in any way (you can check this by running `"x" == "x".strip()`.

You are also checking whether it ends with the empty string, which every string in Python does!

Add some whitespace to your string (eg `"x  "`), and use a whitespace character in your `endswith` call (eg `"x . ".endswith(" ")`) to get a good idea of how the `strip()` function works.