# "not in" identity operator not working when checking empty string for certain characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

When checking if an empty string variable is populated with certain characters, the expression is always evaluated as true. If the newly created string value is empty, it should be false, it does not contain any characters let alone the ones being checked for.

When I hard-code a random character that is not the character being checked for the expression is evaluated as false.

```
difficulty = ''

while difficulty not in 'EMH':
    print('Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard')
    difficulty = input().upper()
```

I expect to see the debugger enter the while loop. What actually happens is it continues past the while block without executing.

Comment: So you want the `while` loop to break if either of `E`, `M`, or `H` is entered ? @walrath21

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is True returned when checking if an empty string is in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-is-true-returned-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Yup, that's right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An empty string is present in any string. Therefore your condition, `difficulty not in 'EMH'` will evaluate to `False` when `difficulty` equals `''`; so the while loop's body won't be executed.

```
In [24]: '' not in 'EMH'                                                                                                                                  
Out[24]: False

In [33]: '' in 'EMH'                                                                                                                                      
Out[33]: True
```

A better approach might be to convert the string `EMH` to a list via `list('EMH')` so that something like `EM` or `EH`, or a empty character doesn't break your loop, or avoid it from starting in the first place

Also as @Blckknght suggested, a better alternative is use a default value of `None` for difficulty.

```
In [3]: difficulty = None                                                                                                                                

In [4]: while difficulty not in list('EMH'): 
   ...:     print('Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard') 
   ...:     difficulty = input().upper() 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                   
Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard
A
Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard
B
Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard
C
Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard
EM
Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard
E

In [5]:
```

Comment: I see.  I wish there was a solution that didn't require me instantiating it as any particular character, but your answer is clear and makes sense. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: A better default value, once you're using a list rather than a string, would be `None`.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you need to use is a list, instead of a string:

```
difficulty = ''

while difficulty not in ['E','M','H']:
    print('Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard')
    difficulty = input().upper()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case for a do-while loop condition. But, python doesn't have it. Please check if the below style suits you:

```
while True:
    print('Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard')
    difficulty = input().upper()
    if difficulty not in 'EMH': #or in ['E', 'M', 'H']
        continue
    else:
        #do some logic
        break
```

---

I do like @Emmet B's suggestion to use ['E', 'M', 'H'] in a loop rather than as a string. It makes sense also as you are expecting one of the character as input and not set of characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you're inclined to live on the bleeding edge of Python, you might be interested in trying out Python 3.8, which is currently being developed (but alpha releases are available). A somewhat controversial new feature (introduced in [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)) is assignment expressions, which let you use `:=` to do an assignment in the middle of another expression.

The loop you're doing could take advantage of such an assignment to do the input and value checking all in one go, without needing to assign a bogus initial value to `difficulty` before entering the loop.

Note that you probably still want to use a list rather than using `not in` with a string on the right side, as the latter does a substring check, not a strict sequence membership test. A substring test like `difficulty not in 'EMH'` will give unintended results for the empty string or the multi-letter inputs `'EM'`, `'MH'` and `'EMH'`. If you might use your different difficulty strings as dictionary keys somewhere (e.g. to look up stats that vary with the difficulty setting), you might test if the input is a key in the dictionary directly, rather than building a separate list.

```
prompt = 'Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard\n'
while (difficulty := input(prompt).upper()) not in ['E', 'M', 'H']:
    pass  # or maybe: print("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that.")

# you can use `difficulty` down here
```

Note that while you *can* use assignment expressions here, it's not necessarily a good idea to do so, just to avoid initializing a variable. You end up bundling up so many different things into a single line (the `while`, the `input` and `upper` calls, the assignment with `:=`, and the `not in` test) that it can be easy to get confused about what is going on. Indeed, in my example above, I ended up creating a *different* variable (`prompt`) because the line would have been too long otherwise.

Comment: I read about this today! Why is this controversial though? The PEP essentially sigs praises of this feature :)

Comment: There were two different kinds of contention to my eyes. Some people didn't like the `:=` spelling, often preferring `expr as name` instead, despite the problems that would create with expressions in `with` and `except` statements (where `as name` means something subtly different). The other issue is a more fundamental one, that assignments have always previously been statements in Python. It's kind of a big deal to change that, and the new feature might make it trickier to teach new programmers the difference between statements and expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is already mentioned (using a `list` will solve the problem, and initializing the variable to `None` is pretty clean, IMHO), but there are so many different ways to do this (despite rule #13 of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

One suggestion I have not seen mentioned yet is to use a separate boolean in the while expression, so you don't have to initialize the `difficulty` variable with an arbitrary invalid value, and don't need other `continue` / `break` / `else` / `pass` statements:

```py
valid_input = False
while not valid_input:
    print('Enter difficulty: E - Easy, M - Medium, H - Hard')
    difficulty = input().upper()
    valid_input = difficulty in ['E', 'M', 'H']
```