# Getting unique values from a column with varying values in pandas and breaking up rows into multiple rows on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the example of the DataFrame:

```
df_movies['genres'].unique()
array(['Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller',
       'Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller',
       'Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy', ...,
       'Adventure|Drama|Action|Family|Foreign',
       'Comedy|Family|Mystery|Romance',
       'Mystery|Science Fiction|Thriller|Drama'], dtype=object)
```

When I try

```
df_movies[df_movies['genres'].str.contains('|')]
```

this gives just lists all rows including the ones with just one category for genre like "Horror", "Documentary" etc.

How do get all unique values from this column? And also what is a way to break up each row into multiple so each row has only one genre associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  I added the movies column, as I would assume your data has other information that the genres relate to.

```
# Recreate data
movies = ['movie_1',
          'movie_2',
          'movie_3',
          'movie_4',
          'movie_5',
          'movie_6']

genres = ['Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller',
          'Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller',
          'Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy',
          'Adventure|Drama|Action|Family|Foreign',
          'Comedy|Family|Mystery|Romance',
          'Mystery|Science Fiction|Thriller|Drama']

import pandas as pd

# Intialize empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create dataframe from data
df['movies'] = movies
df['genres'] = genres
df['genres'] = df['genres'].astype(str)

# Check to make sure data came in right
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.head())

import re

# Create Regex to split genres
regex = r"\|"

# Split genres to new column and store values as a list
df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.split(regex)

# Create new dataframe with each genre from each list on a separate row
df_final = df.explode('genres')

# Join dataframes by index
df_final = df_final.join(df, rsuffix='_other')

# Drop unwanted columns
df_final = df_final.drop(['movies_other', 'genres_other'], axis = 1)

# Get unique genres
unique_genres = df_final['genres'].unique()

# Print results
print(df_final.head())
print(unique_genres)
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a special character. With a contains it would be used to join multiple conditions. For instance `Series.str.contains('foo|seven')` is the same as asking for each row's value (call it `x`): `'foo' in x or 'seven' in x`

Given that, your query is interpreted as `'' in x or '' in x`, which will be `True` for all rows [because the empty string is in all python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-is-true-returned-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another). To literally use the character `'|'` you need to escape it with `'\'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'genres': ['foo|bar', 'no_bar_here']})

df['genres'].str.contains('\|')
0     True
1    False
Name: genres, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Now how do i get a list of all the unique values?

Comment: @sumak in that case you can use `.str.split` to turn each item into its own cell. In this case you don't need to escape the character, so you would do `df_movies['genres'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().unique()`