# What does empty quotation marks('') mean?

Tags: python, string

When I run the code:

```
def test(string):
    return '' in string
test("wolf")
```

It returns `True`. What does `''` mean? I previously thought it meant nothing, but am now unsure. If it was nothing/`None`/`Null` then why does this expression return `True`?

Comment: It is the empty string. And as such it is a substring of every other string. Which is what `'' in string` tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-is-true-returned-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `return` expression (in this case) returns whether or not a string, int, float, etc. is in your variable. In this case, your string is not empty because '' simply means your answer has (or is) a string.

In other words, `''` does not equal `None`.

```
print('' == None)
-> False
```